# What is the -lrt flag in gnu-make?

Tags: gcc, gnu-make

In a later stage of the gnu-make process gmake sent a command similar to:

```
gcc -static foo.so.0 bar.o bizz.o buzz.o -pthreads -lrt
```

In that command, what dos the -lrt mean?

Comment: `-l` = link library, so you're telling gcc to use the `rt` library while compiling this code.

Comment: `-l` says link with library starting with `lib` and ending with `.a` or `.so`.
`rt` stands for Real Time.
`librt` is the realtime extensions library.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That has not related to make; make will never add a flag like that on its own.  Whomever wrote your makefile will have added that flag to the link line themselves.  That is a compilation command, and `-lrt` is a flag passed to the compiler.  The `-l` flag specifies that you should link with a library, and the name of the library follows; so for `-lrt` it means "link with the `rt` library".  This causes the linker to go look for libraries named `librt.a` or `librt.so` (for shared libraries) and link them with the output file.

Comment: for anyone else fresh out of google, `librt` stands for Realtime Extension and has functions such as `clock_gettime()`, `fork`, and `nanosleep()`.